# Syntax error with using session in cshtml

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

When I try to use below variable in my cshtml file, it is giving warning like syntax error.

```
var userid = @HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString();
```

I'm trying to access session value in my mvc cshtml file.

Any thing wrong in the above code?

Comment: try without @ as `var userid =HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString();`

Comment: Try to not make use of this kind of code in the View. Use the controller to populate the user in a view Model. What you're doing is not a good practice. Make your views as skin as possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the variable in a code block:

```
@{ var userid = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString(); }
```

Comment: In this case, I'm not able to get reference of userid variable. Can you tell me how to get it?

Comment: It should work, are you referencing the value within the same code block? You could also try accessing the session variable directly by way of '@HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString()'

Comment: Yes, I'm referencing within the same code block. And @HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString() is working but it is giving a warning as syntax error.